# date constraint, add exception for null:0001-01-01

Tags: php, postgresql

In my postgresql db there are two fields: open_date, close_date.
There is a constraint, close date not before open date - open_date<=close_date.

I'm trying to insert via php/PDO and it parses null as 0001-01-01, which technically is before the open date - even though it is null.

How do I add to the constraint to make an exception for 0001-01-01?

Comment: give the exact definition of check constraint please

Comment: You need to show the PHP code (the way you pass the date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it to null in your check:

`open_date<=nullif(close_date,'0001-01-01')`

or expand condition:

`open_date<=close_date AND close_date != '0001-01-01'`

Not sure what performs better.